# How to check whether user exists in perforce or not through python script

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I want to make script to remove the terminated user from perforce but to do that first have to check whether user exists in perforce or not.
I tried below command in python script but did not work.

```
p4.run("users"|grep user)
```

Is there any command in perforce or any way to use above command in my script.

Comment: What is the output of `p4.run`?

Comment: @HaiVu invalid syntax

Comment: I don't have p4python installed, so I'm just fishing here. How about if you try: `p4.run("users", user)` -- if you get an error such as *foo - no such user(s)* then the user does not exist. Otherwise, you will get a dict containing the user info.

Comment: this doesnt work. it gives me nothing. No error no output

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
p4.run("users"|grep user)
```

won't work. You seem to think that `p4.run()` executes an operating system command line that you can then pipe output to. That's not how `p4.run()` works. It is an API function that takes command strings that are similar to what you would type on a command line, but that is where the similarity ends. Try

```
myusers = p4.run("users")
```

and then work with what Perforce gives back to you in `myusers`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points. I don't know why your command failed, but guess you have not logged in (i.e. connect using `p4.connect()`). I have tried the following and found it working:

```
import getpass
import P4

def get_user(user):
    """
    Get information for a single user

    Return None if not found, or a dict similar to this one:
        {
            'Update': '1422308004',
            'Access': '1515088079',
            'User': 'abc', 
            'FullName': 'Anna Bell Clark',
            'Type': 'standard',
            'Email': 'abc@example.com'
        }
    """
    p4 = P4.P4()
    p4.password = getpass.getpass()
    p4.connect()
    try:
        users_info = p4.run('users', user)
        return users_info[0]
    except P4.P4Exception:
        return None


user = 'abc'
print(get_user(user))
```

## Notes

- use `getpass.getpass()` to prompt for the password from console. `getpass` does not echo the password, so it is reasonably safe to keep your password hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample P4Python code:

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/API/python/main/test/test_p4python.py#747

```
def _delete_user(self, new_user):
    user = self.p4.fetch_user(new_user)
    self.p4.save_user(user)
    self._change_user(config.p4_user)
    self.p4.login(config.p4_password)
    print self.p4.delete_user("-f", new_user)
```

This demonstrates fetching a user, logging in as that user, and deleting the user.